# Creating a Trigger in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger in Oracle SQLPlus. The trigger deals with two tables:
users{id, name, status}
offerings{id, title, price, userid, status};

I would like that when the user table is updated an the status of a entry is change to 2 that all offerings that the user has made will be changed to i (for inactive)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_offering_status
BEFORE UPDATE ON users
WHEN (new.status = 2)
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
Userid INTEGER;
BEGIN
USERID :=  :old.userid;
    UPDATE offering
    SET status = 'i'
    WHERE userid = old.userid;
END;
```

I am getting the error ORA-04077: WHEN clause cannot be used with table level triggers. But I am not sure how to do it without a when clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's happening because your `WHEN` clause is in the wrong place. Put it after the `FOR EACH ROW` and you should be all set:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_offering_status
BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.status = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put it into `IF` & `END IF` instead of `WHEN`